# Why won't it recognize my method?

Tags: java, debugging

```
import java.lang.String;
public class Word
{
    /** 
     * constructs a Word with String value s
     * @param s is string value of Word
     */
    public Word(String s)
    {
        original = s;
    }

    /**
     * reverses letters in original string 
     * @return a string that is a reverse of original
     */
    public String reverse()
    {
        String temp = original;
        String areverse = "";
        int x;
        for (x = temp.length() ; x>0 || x==0 ; x -- )
        {   
            areverse = temp.substring(x);
        }
        return areverse;
    }

    /**    
     * determines is word is a palindrome
     * @return true if word is a palindrome, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean isPalindrome()
    {
        boolean flag = false;
        String temp = original;
        if (temp.equals(temp.reverse()))
            flag = true;
        return flag;

    }

    /** 
     * Alternate method to determine if word is a palindrome
     * @return true if word is a palindrome, false otherwise    
     */
    public boolean isPalindrome2()
    { 
        String temp = original;
        int x = temp.length();
        boolean flag = false;
        int y = 0;
        while (temp.subtring(y).equals(temp.substring(x)) && (x>0 || x==0))
        {
            x--;
            y++;
        }
        if (x==0)
            flag=true;
        return flag;


    }

    private String original;
}
```

I have to write this program that finds the reverse of a word, and determines if a word is a palindrome in two different ways. I was only given the method names and then the comments about the methods, but all the code in the methods is mine. When I use the reverse() method in the first palindrome method, bluej tells me it cannot find the variable or method 'reverse', even though I define it earlier in the code. What's my problem? thanks

Comment: This wasn't included, but this is at the top   import java.lang.String;
public class Word
{
   
    public Word(String s)
    {
        original = s;
    }

Comment: [Rubber duck debugging](http://www.rubberduckdebugging.com/) would go a long way here.

Comment: I think we need to see where the error actually is reported (where you're calling the `reverse()` method).

Comment: @markspace No, it is pretty obvious. He is calling reverse() on an instance of String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're setting temp to a string, however the reverse method is not inside the string class but rather your class but you're trying to find it in the string when you did

```
temp.reverse();
```

You can get around this by making the reverse method take in a string AND return a string, the string it takes in is what it's reversing and the return is the reversed string.

```
public String reverse(String string)
```

Then you call the method in YOUR class

```
if (temp.equals(reverse(temp)))
    flag = true;
```

So the new reverse method would look like

```
public String reverse(String string)
{
    String areverse = "";
    for (int x = string.length(); x>0; x--)
    {   
        areverse += string.charAt(x - 1);
    }
    return areverse;
}
```

Comment: I can't change the method but I will do it anyway and just take a couple points off.. thanks though!

Comment: If it's gonna take a point off you could try
 if (temp.equals(reverse()) flag = true;

Answer (score 1):

You are invoking reverse on the String object "temp". You have defined the `reverse`-method in the `Word` class, so you need to invoke it on a `Word` object.

Comment: gotchya... How do I do that then?

Comment: You can instantiate a new Word object by Word myNewWordObject = new Word("someString"). Then you can call reverse on that object: myNewWordObject.reverse(). In your isPalindrome method, it could look like: if (temp.equals(new Word(temp).reverse()))

Answer (score 0):

You should be using

```
new StringBuilder(original).reverse().toString()
```

in order to get the reverse. The method reverse doesn´t exist in String type.

Comment: We can't use StringBuilder

Comment: Your method wouldn't work. The method reverse is defined in the Word class, not the String class.